# Script for finding out disk number

Tags: external-hard-drive, script, diskpart

I have an external hard disk with two partitions. The first one is an UDF partition and the second partition is a Veracrypt partition. Now I want to use a batch script to load the Veracrypt partition using Veracrypt Command Line. But I cannot find the GUID of the partition. Mountvol does not list the partition. The only approach is to use the Device\HardDisk [number]/Partition [number] approach. Now I can get the correct harddisk and partition number using Diskpart. But I cannot implement it into a script. If anyone could help me out in this, it'd be a great help.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I'm guessing Windows but I;m not sure. If it is Windows, which version?

Comment: It is Windows 7 32bit Professional Edition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. I did it in Powershell though. Had to learn Powershell from the scratch for this.

```
$diskdrv = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_DiskDrive -Filter "Caption='WD Elements 1078 USB Device'"
if ($diskdrv.SerialNumber.Contains("WXS1E94D125E"))
{
    $index = $diskdrv.Index
    Write-Host Hard Disk found at Index $Index
    $volume = "\Device\Harddisk"+ $index + "\Partition2"
    write-host Volume located at $volume
    &"I:\Applications\VeraCrypt Portable\veracrypt.exe" /v $volume /lS /e /b  /q
 }
```